# getAnnotations method in a joinPoint is not listing one of the annotations on the method

Tags: java, spring, java-7, aop, aspectj

I'm working with AOP in spring:

I have written an annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotation {

}
```

And I use it on a controller method:

```
@ResponseBody
@TestAnnotation
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/path/{variable}")
public return_type controller_call(@PathVariable String variable) {
    return service.methodName(variable);
}
```

In the advice I have written the following code:

```
 MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    String methodName = signature.getMethod().getName();
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = signature.getMethod().getParameterTypes();
    Annotation[] annotations = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes).getAnnotations();
```

This lists the RequestMapping and the ResponseBody annotation but it doesn't list my TestAnnotation.

Any idea why??

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible example and make it as short as possible.

Answer (score 1):

For me this works, maybe you are doing something wrong. Probably your sample code does not really reflect your situation. I have replicated this situation in a plain Java + AspectJ setup, merely putting the Spring libs on the classpath, but not running with Spring AOP. It should be the same result with Spring AOP, though, because pointcut matching is just like in native AspectJ.

**Sample annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotation {}
```

**Sample class with entry point:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

public class Application {
    @ResponseBody
    @TestAnnotation
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/path/{variable}")
    public String controller_call(@PathVariable String variable) {
        return "dummy value";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().controller_call("my/path");
    }
}
```

**Aspect with sample pointcut/advice:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Before("execution(!static * *..Application.*(..))")
    public void myAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(joinPoint);
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        String methodName = signature.getMethod().getName();
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = signature.getMethod().getParameterTypes();
        Annotation[] annotations = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes).getAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations)
            System.out.println(annotation);
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.controller_call(String))
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody()
@de.scrum_master.app.TestAnnotation()
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping(headers=[], name=, value=[/path/{variable}], produces=[], method=[PUT], params=[], consumes=[])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution was to set ensure that the runtime retention policy is set and the target type is a method.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)    
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation { }
```